# How to achieve an average life expectancy of several centuries in the Stone Age?

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, humans, super-powers

Min (c. 1499-2006) (the name of the animal was given in honor of the oldest Chinese dynasty, which ruled exactly at the time when the baby clam was born), given to a specimen of the mollusk species Arctica islandica of the Venerid family, washed ashore in Iceland in  2006, whose age was determined by counting the growth rings on its shell.  Min was recognized as the oldest individual (non-colony) animal ever discovered whose age can be accurately determined.  Initially, the age of the mollusk was declared equal to 405 years, later it was increased to 507 years.

How can I ensure a similar (at least 300 years) life expectancy for my genetically modified superhumans, who are representatives of a new species of people?

Note: it is worth mentioning that at the time of the actions of my story, this new kind of improved people was at the level of development of the Stone Age, that is, if the average life expectancy in the Stone Age for ordinary people was about 30 years, then for them it should be 300-350 years without  any medical intervention from the outside.

Also, considering some questions about their metabolic rate or the duration of the growing up process, I would like to mention that their metabolic rate practically does not differ from ours, just like growing up.

Comment: Galapagos tortoises are much heavier than humans, much more closely related to humans than clams, and in good conditions can live more than 150 years. If you need people who can live 300 years once they grow past childhood diseases, than just say that your people live 300 years once they grow past childhood diseases. It's perfectly believable. (And that 30 years average life expectancy in the Stone Age is the average for all people, including the many who died in childhood; people who made it past childhood lived the usual pre-industrial "three score and ten" years.)

Comment: According to the Bible, that's exactly what happened.

Comment: Teeth may become a problem. It's difficult to keep them disease-free for a normal lifetime, let alone a longer one.

Comment: Does it matter how we get to the average? Is it Ok if some people live for thousands of years, but more would be dying young, giving 300-350 years on average?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have to deal with one of the main human lifespan-limiting factors: Cancer.
Cancerous cells are caused by mutations in said cells, most usually in growth blockers and regulators.
A cell still catches errors so that approx. 1/1000000000 or one in a billion nucleotides are altered.

If your alternate humanity has extra steps to stop mutations, **such as more checking enzyme processes and UV ray insulation**, then there's a considerable chance that they'll live longer.

Secondary to the above point, alternate-humanity will need to most probably need to maintain a much larger immune system to prevent pneumonia and the like.**Stem cells and constant brain growth** would be necessary unless you want a bunch of veggie-brained or dementia-infused people running around. The increased Stem cells would also be able to assist with heart problems, etc.

**Enhanced muscular growth** leading to a lack of frailty when they are old (compared to humanity) and **constant rebuilding of the eyes and hearing** need to be regenerative also when compared to humanity.

The body would need a way to clear blood clots easily or seizures and strokes and aneurysms would kill frequently, but not so much that they bleed out due to a lack of coagulation.
Think **situational anticoagulants** or an **appendix remodeled to control the releasing of platelets and anticoagulants**

The hypothalamus is linked to aging, so to the best of my knowledge, enhanced stem cells in the hypothalamic portion of the brain trending towards endurance would decrease most mental aging, etc.

All in all, it's just a lost of small adaptations down at the cellular level that would increase lifespan, but rather difficult to source enough nutrition to allow constant regeneration at a growth and reinforcement rate of childhood for many, many years.

#### TLDR, you would need enhanced stem cell growth and lasting length- meaning a lock at child-ish stem cells, a more controlled and less prevalent G0 phase for enhanced endurance and brain cell, as well as a protein that would police aging and reverse it.

Feel free to edit my answer, I'm by no means a professional and am just a student thinking.

Comment: I need as detailed a description as possible, saying that I need to cure cancer and dementia, you did not help me in any way, I know this without you, tell me how to solve these problems (instructions).

Comment: @FrenchThompson I'm sorry for my lack of clarification, I'll work on it whenever I have a bit of free time.

Comment: I hope I've clarified somewhat, sorry if I wasn't incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Be shorter than 5 feet 8 inches, bleed often, preferably bleed a minimum of 3 times a year.
starve yourself, eat lots of fruit... But not enough to fuel you.
Work a 40 hours a week of a strenous job, be born with a mental resistance so strong that even if you see everyone you love dying in wars, it doesn't traumatize you.
Sleep 6 to 8 hours a night,  then take some naps during the day.
Have more than 3 friends, get married, have children.

Thats what everyone who lived over 100 years has in common.

As for living more than that... You need magic or CRISPR